# IntelliJ IDEA reports incompatible types for Gradle on authentication element

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

In Gradle, to pass authentication information to a repository definition for publishing, you use the `authentication` element (which comes from class `MavenRemoteRepository`). This might look this:

```
subprojects {
  uploadArchives {
    repositories {
      mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: 'https://repo.cool.org/') {
          authentication(userName: "public", password: "secret")
} } } } }
```

This can be top-level. However, when this is wrapped in a `subprojects` element (and *only* then), IntelliJ reports that the arguments cannot be applied. It seems IntelliJ suddenly assumes that `authentication` comes from `AuthenticationSupported`, while Gradle still finds the intended element.

Is this a bug in IntelliJ? Can the `build.gradle` file be transformed such that both Gradle and IntelliJ are satisfied? Or will I have to just suppress the warning?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177227 for the related problem.

Comment: Thanks. That’s actually almost an answer ;-)